# dotnet test very slow

Tags: .net, unit-testing, azure-devops

I have a solution that contains more than one project in dotnet 6. I try to run the unit test on azure devops but it is extraordinarily long. I noticed that this is due to ef core migration. When I remove the migration folder from my solution, it is faster. I have about 100 migrations. I use EF Core 5.

With the migration file it takes 1h
Without the migration file it takes 5 minutes

How to make my tests faster

My tests for test in my pipeline :

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Test
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: '**/*.UnitTests.csproj'
      publishTestResults: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --settings $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/CodeCoverage.runsettings'
```

Comment: Is it this slow when running locally? Also it is hard to guess what is actually slow in your case without seeing repro. The command itself is not a repro.

Comment: Note that applying 100 migration definitely will take time for obvious reasons.

Comment: Locally it’s fast. And as part of the unit tests, I don’t ask for the application of migrations